# Displaying icons in tab bar with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, icons

I am new to react native and am trying to display icons within my tab menu.

I have tried using FontAwesome, FontAwesome5, react-native-vector-icons and Ionicons. None of these seems to be displaying any icons and I don't know why.

[image: tab bar]

Here is my code.

```js
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: HomeScreen,
    defaultnavigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="home" color="#ccc"size={25} />
        )
    },
  },
   
  Events: { 
    screen: EventScreen,
     defaultnavigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="home" color="#ccc"size={25} />
        )

  },
  About: { 
    screen: AboutScreen,
     defaultnavigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="home" color="#ccc"size={25} />
        )
  }
},
 { tabBarOptions: { 
    showIcon: true,
    activeTintColor: '#D4AF37',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
      style: {
       backgroundColor: 'white', 
},
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
  }
}
 }
);
```

Comment: Are you add the icon fonts to your Xcode project?

Comment: yes I have done that now and everything works.

Comment: I'm Glad that helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeNavigation,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        title:  'home',
        tabBarIcon: <Icon name="home" color="#ccc"size={25} />,
      }),

    },
 {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    lazy: false,
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#d63921',
        labelPosition: 'below-icon'
      },
  },
);
```

feel free for doubts.

Comment: now I get an error that says "unrecognised font-family"